# C# WPF Files Creation

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-access

How can I create access 2000-2003 file using C# WPF and add tables in, data in and perform queries on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this like in any other C# .NET application; it does not matter whether or not WPF is used.

Microsoft [Knowledge Base Article 317881](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317881/en-us) explains how to create an empty database in C#.

You can add data and perform queries using OLE DB. The MSDN Library has some samples, e.g. [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288452(v=VS.71).aspx).

In order to create tables, you could execute the SQL statement CREATE TABLE. For example,

```
   string cmd = "CREATE TABLE myTable (id INTEGER, txt CHAR(20))";
   OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, oleDbConnection);
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

creates a table with the two columns "id" and "txt".

I hope, this helps.